# Are financial trusts or cryptocurrency investments exempt from the SSI maximum resource limit?

Tags: united-states, cryptocurrency, social-security, trusts

As a recipient of SSI, I am not permitted to exceed a maximum resource limit of $2000.

The SSA definition of "resources" is vague, but is basically liquid assets, including: bank accounts, stocks, mutual funds, savings bonds, land, vehicles, and life insurance.

Exceptions are made for a home that is the recipient's residence, one vehicle that is in active use, burial spaces, etc.

But what about assets like cryptocurrency and/or financial trusts? Are they exempt from this policy?

Comment: Why would they be exempt?

Answer (score 3):

Cryptocurrencies would almost certainly be included. The [SSA](https://www.ssa.gov/ssi/text-resources-ussi.htm) lists the resources that are included, of which one is:

> Anything else you own which could be changed to cash and used for food or shelter

There are exemptions for your house and one car so that your life needs are not adversely impacted; I cannot think of any reason why crypto would be exempt for that reasons.

[Trusts](https://www.ssa.gov/ssi/spotlights/spot-trusts.htm) are generally included if you have access to the resources within them, or the trust was set up for a special purpose, such as a special needs or disability trust.

The principal is, if you can sell it or access the cash, it reduces your need and thus your benefit.